# Explicit example of saturated (complete) set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

We say that a set $X$ (maybe class, I don't know) is saturated or is complete if for every $Y\in X$, $Y$ is a proper subset (maybe proper subclass?) of $X$:
$$ Y\subset X $$

An example of a complete subset is any ordinal. However, I can't imagine ''how'' is an ordinal. So, can you give me an explicit set that is complete?

For example, I think $1=\{\emptyset\}$ is complete, since their unique element is the $\emptyset$ that is also a proper subset. I have also tried with $2=1\cup\{1\}=\Big\{ \emptyset,\{\emptyset\} \Big\}$, and again $\emptyset\in 2$ and it is also a subset and, since $\emptyset\in 2$, $\{\emptyset\}\subset 2$.

At this point I suppose every natural is a complete set, since ordinals are a generalization of naturals.
So can give more examples rather than naturals?

**Addeundm.** Thanks to @AndreasBlass for indicates my mistake.

Comment: $2=1\cup\{1\}=\{\emptyset\}\cup\{\{\emptyset\}\}=\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}$, and this set is saturated in your terminology (or, in the usual terminology, transitive).

Comment: Oh, my god. If I compute wrong the union... It seems logical, since ordinals are a generalization of naturals. I will edit my question!

Comment: $\{ \{ 2, 3 \}, 0, 1, 2, 3 \}$ would be an example of a set satisfying this condition which is not an ordinal.

Comment: @DanielSchepler I suppose here you mean $0=\emptyset$, $1=0\cup\{0\}$ and so on,  don't you?

Comment: Yes, I'm still using the standard encoding of naturals in ZFC.  So a smaller example would be $\{ \{ 1 \}, 0, 1 \} = \{ \{\}, \{\{\}\}, \{\{\{\}\}\} \}$.

Comment: @DanielSchepler: Perfect.